# puppeteer can't run open the url in a simple code

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, chromium

I have this code:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    ignoreDefaultArgs: ["--disable-extensions"],
  });


  const page = await browser.newPage(); 
  await page.goto("https://google.com");

  await browser.close();
})();
```

when I run it, the chromium browser opens, but :

[image]

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

I downgraded my puppeteer version to 18.1.0 and runned ly code again and it worked as I expected, Thank you!